# EditText and Paint together in android like Note+

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-canvas

I want to develop an application like Note+. This application install automatically in some model of cell phone like Samsung Note 5.
In this application user can enter Text into EditText and change input mode to graphic and draw line by finger over text.
User can Change mode to Text/Graphic by click on a toolbar.

My code for draw line in graphic mode (Canvas):

```
package com.note.vastac;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyDrawView extends View {
    public Bitmap  mBitmap;
    public Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint   mPaint;


    public MyDrawView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(9);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);


    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
        this.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());   
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return bmp;
    }

    public void clear(){
        mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        invalidate();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Then using MyDrawView class by include it into xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Test">

    <com.note.vastac.MyDrawView
        android:id="@+id/draw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.note.vastac.MyDrawView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTextMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Text" >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGraphicMode"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Graphic" >
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The question is: How to change mode from graphic (draw line by finger) to Text (enter text by keyboard) ?

Comment: check this tuto [https://blog.uptech.team/how-to-create-beautiful-text-stickers-for-android-10eeea0cee09]